# How to do javascript online k-means clustering for many dimensions

Tags: javascript, cluster-analysis, k-means

I found many examples of javascript online k-means clustering, but all of the are for 2 dimensions.

If I have 56 dimensions (for example), how can I do the clustering?

**Bonus question:**

Could it be possible, having some new data, to predict some value looking the clusters (like, 76% of belonging to cluster x, so the value should be y)

Comment: 56 *numerical* values?

Comment: It was an example. I have not counted them. It may be only 34 variables

Comment: The main part was, whether these values are numeric; in a meaningful way  (i.e. comparable). Most people fail at getting usable results out of such data because of preprocessing and such.

Answer (score 2):

k-means algorithm should be easy to port to any number of dimensions. It looks like this:

1. Randomly choose centers of clusters.
2. For each point check, what is the nearest cluster.
3. Compute new cluster center by computing avarage from all points.
4. Repeat until cluster centers don't change.

In 2d, you check the distance between `(x1, x2)` and `(y1, y2)` in 2. like this `(x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2` (you don't need to use square root, if you are using distance only to compare it with another distance). In 56 dimensions, you just have 56 components.

In 2d, you compute cluster center by taking avarage of all points. Take the first dimension of all points and take the average `avg1`, take all the second dimensions `avg2` up to 56 and your new cluster center will be `(avg1, avg2, avg3 ... avg56)`.

What is not easy is that it is very expensive. Check out algorithms for dimensionality reduction (feature extraction) like PCA.

Also make sure, that all freatures are normalized. For example - they have ranges between `(-100, 100)`.

If you need more information, check out Machine Learning course at [coursera](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/preview).
Week 8 is all about clustering and its traps.